# Significance of the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of an interferometer?

Tags: optics, interferometry

An interferometer acting on $N$ modes can be described in terms of an $N \times N$ unitary transformation $U$ acting on the creation or annihilation operators of the modes.

I'm wondering if there is any physical significance to the eigenmodes/eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the interferometer unitary? Are interferometers ever designed with these quantities in mind?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what you are talking about is really description of an interferometer in terms of *scattering matrix*, mapping input states on the output ones. Scattering matrix is ubiquituous in QFT, and every serious QM book devotes a chapter to it.

Unitarily is of course and important property - e.g., when applied to solid state devices, it reflects particle conservation - read on Landauer-Büttiker formalism for more information. When applied to solid state Aharonov-Bohm interferometers it leads to a remarkable phenomenon of *phase rigidity*.